# Unity gradient color fade

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a fade between two colors on a weather system in C#. I'm using the following code to fade the color of the keys of a gradient used by the clouds:

```
void ChangeWeather(string to)
{
    Gradient g = skyController.WispyColorGradientColor[0];
    GradientColorKey[] gck = new GradientColorKey[5];
    GradientAlphaKey[] gak = new GradientAlphaKey[2];

    gak[0].alpha = 1f;
    gak[1].alpha = 1f;
    gak[0].time = 0f;
    gak[1].time = 100f;

    Color color = new Color();

    skyController.WispyColorGradientColor[0] = g;

    //Set the initial value
    gck[0] = g.colorKeys[0];
    gck[1] = g.colorKeys[1];
    gck[2] = g.colorKeys[2];
    gck[3] = g.colorKeys[3];
    gck[4] = g.colorKeys[4];

    //refer te variables
    g.colorKeys[0] = gck[0];
    g.colorKeys[1] = gck[1];
    g.colorKeys[2] = gck[2];
    g.colorKeys[3] = gck[3];
    g.colorKeys[4] = gck[4];

    //set the times
    gck[0].time = .209f;
    gck[1].time = .238f;
    gck[2].time = .50f;
    gck[3].time = .756f;
    gck[4].time = .791f;

    if (to == "clear")
    {
        ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(cleanCloudsColors[0], out color);

        gck[0].color = Color.Lerp(g.colorKeys[0].color, color, changeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        gck[4].color = Color.Lerp(g.colorKeys[4].color, color, changeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(cleanCloudsColors[1], out color);

        gck[1].color = Color.Lerp(g.colorKeys[1].color, color, changeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        gck[3].color = Color.Lerp(g.colorKeys[3].color, color, changeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(cleanCloudsColors[2], out color);

        gck[2].color = Color.Lerp(g.colorKeys[2].color, color, changeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        Debug.Log("Changing");
    }
}
```

The "skyController.WispyColorGradientColor[0]" refers to a Gradient in a array list and "ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString" just convert a hex color (like #fff) to RGB. It log "Changing" but, well, the clouds were changing color without fade, so I made these changes and it does not change more. I NEED THE FADE, but nothing seems to work. :(

**EDIT**: I used a code like it to try to fade between colors in 5 seconds:

```
float fadeTime = 5f;

void Update(){
    //...
    if (param)
        StartCoroutine(fadeColor(0, Color.grey, Color.white));
    //...
}

IEnumerator fadeColor (int index, Color from, Color to){
    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < fadeTime){
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        gradient.colorKeys[index].color = Color.Lerp(from, to, counter / fadeTime);
    }

    yield return null;
}
```

It change the color, but change instantly and I want to change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to understand your code and but all I know is that you want to fade between two Colors. This should be done with `Coroutine`. The function below should fade between two colors in any GameObject. You can easily modify it to suit whatever you are doing.

The function call below will change the GameObject's color to red in 5 seconds.

```
StartCoroutine(fadeColor(obj, Color.red, 5));
```

Fade Function:

```
IEnumerator fadeColor(GameObject objectToFade, Color newColor, float fadeTime = 3)
{
    int mode = 0;

    Color currentColor = Color.clear;

    SpriteRenderer tempSPRenderer = objectToFade.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    Image tempImage = objectToFade.GetComponent<Image>();
    RawImage tempRawImage = objectToFade.GetComponent<RawImage>();
    Renderer tempRenderer = objectToFade.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    //Check if this is a Sprite
    if (tempSPRenderer != null)
    {
        currentColor = tempSPRenderer.color;
        mode = 0;
    }
    //Check if Image
    else if (tempImage != null)
    {
        currentColor = tempImage.color;
        mode = 1;
    }
    //Check if RawImage
    else if (tempRawImage != null)
    {
        currentColor = tempRawImage.color;
        mode = 2;
    }
    //Check if 3D Object
    else if (tempRenderer != null)
    {
        currentColor = tempRenderer.material.color;
        mode = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        yield break;
    }

    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < fadeTime)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        switch (mode)
        {
            case 0:
                tempSPRenderer.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, newColor, counter / fadeTime);
                break;
            case 1:
                tempImage.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, newColor, counter / fadeTime);
                break;
            case 2:
                tempRawImage.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, newColor, counter / fadeTime);
                break;
            case 3:
                tempRenderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, newColor, counter / fadeTime);
                break;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It don't fade the Color component at the time it was passed (5 secs), it changes instantly... :'(

Comment: @VinciusOliveira I don't understand your comment. You mean you want it to change instantly without wasting time? If so pass 0.05 to it. `StartCoroutine(fadeColor(obj, Color.red, 0.05));`

Comment: I don't want that it change instantly, I want that wast time.

Comment: @VinciusOliveira Ok. I you want to do it over time,use the code in my answer. Just pass in the GameObject, the color and the time(how long to change). That's it. The code above will work with any GameObject. What are you having problem with?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it does not changing over time. It's changing instantly (I'm using your code).

Comment: @VinciusOliveira tested my code before posting. I have been using that for anything and it works without any problem.  The problem is likely from your side. Put **EDIT** in your question and post how you are using the code.

Comment: Edited, I put the necessary part of the code, now it's more easy to understand, I think.

Comment: That's not how to make an edit. I fixed it for you. Don't touch the original post. You said you are using my code but that's not true. You modified it heavily. Just using my code should fix it. Also you use the Gradient class for animation but you don't need it here because we manually animating color. You don't.

Comment: @VinciusOliveira Since use my function or change `gradient.colorKeys[index].color` to your `theGameObjectToChange.color`. Also rename `from`. You can't use that word because it is a C# keyword.

Comment: I used to change `gradient.colorKeys[index].color`, but it's changing instantly, not over time. I'm not using a var named `from`, I wrote here, but not in the code :p

Comment: I will mark it as the answer, because I know that it's correct, even if it not worked correctly for me.